# Adding list of time delta to a list of datetime objects?

Tags: python, data-analysis

I have one list which has objects in the format "00:07:00" and add this to another list which has objects in the "2016-09-02 14:41:00" format.

When I searched the type, for "00:07:00", it said "pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas.Timedelta.

And for "2016-09-02 14:41:00", it said "pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp".ana
How can I add both the lists ?

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: can you show toy example and expected resuit?

Comment: I don't have a toy example because I don't know how to do it. And the result I am expecting is the addition of one object to another. Example:- "00:07:00 + 2016-09-02 14:41:00" = "2016-09-02 14:48:00"

Comment: You can literally just add them, Pandas will work with them! You can subtract, add, divide, etc `timedelta`s and `datetime`s. E.g.: `pd.Series(pd.date_range('2018-9-1', periods=5)) + pd.to_timedelta(np.arange(5), unit='s')`

Answer (score 1):

I don't have panda installed, but according to documentation, panda timestamps and timedeltas can be added.  So something like this might work:

```
result = [t + d for t, d in zip(timestamps, deltas)]
```

Answer (score 1):

you can convert the timestamp column value to time only. using below example:

```
df['date_time'].dt.time
```

Then add the two columns having same type i.e timedelta.

```
df['new_time'] = df['first_time'] + df['date_time']
```